# Some sms like OTPs, ATM transaction message are not being received on my LUMIA 525

Tags: sms

Since last two days Some sms like OTPs, ATM transaction message, IRCTC msg or online recharge confirmation sms are not being received on my LUMIA 525 whereas the text sms are working properly. Please resolve

Comment: This sounds like an issue from the operator. Not a defect of Lumia 525.

Comment: I agree. Have you checked with your carrier?

Comment: Dear, if it's an operator's issue how could the text msgs are being received. By the way, I did had a check through the operator and everything is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Same  problem occurred with my lumia 525. To solve this, go to main settings, then go to call+SMS filter. It must be turned on. tap it to make it off. Before doing this, if you want to check what all messages are being blocked, then go to messaging window and then go to settings - then blocked messages. For me the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have operator issue or you have DND (do not disturb) activated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings => System/call + SMS filter and check there is no blocked SMS settings.